# Add to Cart Programmatically

Tags: square-connect

Our shop sells ingredients and supplies, but it's a hassle for our customers to scroll through our entire huge inventory to get the few things they need or just click some of our pre-built recipes.

I'm trying to make a script that will add items programmatically on our website, but I'm running into problems.  Since SquareUp uses cookies to store the cart, I can't send any data to the cart because of cross-domain access.  I've tried using the embedded iframe menu, but that still doesn't let me filter any results or even add some script to "hack" a mouseclick on items to add recipes.

I don't know if this belongs in the Connect API tag, but this was the last place that I figured could help me.  I've read the docs and saw that billing wasn't available, but I'm only adding items to a cart.  I would think that I could have some sort of `?cart-[shopname]=` query appended to the "checkout" link. From there, I could use the Connect API to find the item/variation codes and create the JSON markup to be added to the cart's cookie.

Basically, my problem is that I know of no way to add items to the cart programmatically.

We would like to keep using SquareUp, but we'd get more sales from Magento or Shopify since we can filter results AND programmatically add entire recipes to the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do what you're trying to accomplish through the Square online store. It's really only intended as a turnkey solution; there are't any public APIs that you can use to manipulate it programmatically. As you've discovered, your browser will prevent you from manipulating the online store's cookies or calling its backend APIs due to cross-origin policies.

Comment: That's the answer I wasn't hoping for, but I was pretty sure was the case.  Thank you.  Hopefully they'll do something like that in the future if enough people want that feature.